# Observer pattern - Does observable needs to be always abstract?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, observable, observer-pattern

I am new to design patterns , I am learning Observer pattern for that I went to many sites ,where I found the below UML diagram

[image]

So my question is on the UML or class design.If the purpose of the observer pattern is to notify the observers about the change in state of subject/object,     Why the subject needs to be abstract can’t it be a ConcreteSubject directly as shown below:

[image]

What are the disadvantages or violations if we create a Subject as ConcreteSubject.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the purpose of defining the abstract subject class is to provide a base implementation of the properties and methods needed for the Observers to subscribe and receive notifications.

A more generic alternative would be to provide an interface. Or perhaps the abstract class is in fact implementing a more generic interface that only defines the methods that have to be implemented.

In other words the advantage of providing an interface is that you don't need to know the class that implements it.
The advantage of using an abstract class is that you have a base implementation of the methods needed to add or remove observers and to send them notifications. And you take advantage of this by deriving the class.

Answer (score 1):

Making *Concrete Observer* dependent upon *Concrete subject* will solve one problem [Type casting in update method as update(ConcreteSubject cs)] but at the cost of generic nature of Pattern.

*Concrete Subject* and *Abstract Subject* (Observable) have clear demarcation of responsibilities namely - Implement Business logic and be an Observable across application and take care of Observers.

In case we avoid using Subject, every business class requiring Observers (May be added down the line) will have to repeat the code of *Subject*. (Extending one Concrete Subject from Another Concrete Subject is OO violation).

Best way will be to use *Abstract Subject* and **keep extensions and code reuse open.**